# How to better execute commands through queuing?

Tags: c#

My program needs to perform a series of operations as the program runs (such as logging to local computer, uploading data to webapi, etc.). These operations are very frequent, but the immediacy is not very strong, so I do not want to execute them separately every time, which will greatly affect the performance of IO and network.

My idea is to process them one by one through a queue in a separate process. This is what I do now:

```
ConcurrentQueue<LogModel> LogQueue=new ConcurrentQueue<LogModel>();
Task.Run(async()=>{
    while(true)
    {
      if(LogQueue.TryDequeue(out var _result))
      {
        ///Store the log.
      }
      await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
});
```

Although my method is feasible, when there are no elements in the queue, it becomes a meaningless endless loop. This becomes so awkward that it makes me question whether this code design idea is correct.
So here I hope you can provide suggestions on how to deal with a situation like mine (to obtain better performance and stability)? Thank you.

Comment: You are making an HTTP connection between the client and server for each command.  The connection closes after each response.  Every command has to open a new connection.  So using a HTTP Socket instead of  http client is the usual solution.  A Web Socket does not close after each command.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets?view=net-8.0

Comment: @jdweng This really doesn't help me, because webapi is a third party and I can't ask them to use websocket instead.

Comment: Use synchronization primitives: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives. You can have your loop Wait on an eventhandle and then have Enqueue also Set or Signal that eventhandle.

Comment: What about _Blocking_Queue?

Comment: This is a bit complicated and I'm not sure if it's what I need. And my program will run on Linux (through Avalonia), it seems that some functions are only supported on Windows. @rene

Comment: @Fildor I feel that BlockingCollection should be what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *concurrent* collections allow multiple threads to safely add/remove items. What you want is collections that are threadsafe and also support signalling, i.e., the ability for a consumer to wait until there are items available (and likewise for a producer to wait until there is space available).

A modern solution is a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). Channels provide asynchronous producer/consumer queues.

```
Channel<LogModel> LogQueue = Channel.CreateBounded<LogModel>(32);
Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await foreach (var _result in Channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
  {
    ///Store the log.
  }
});
```

If you do need to use the concurrent collections, another out-of-the-box solution is [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), which builds on top of the concurrent collections. The concurrent collections implement [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), and `BlockingCollection<T>` uses one of those concurrent collections underneath. By default it uses `ConcurrentQueue<T>` unless you specify another one.

A consumer using `BlockingCollection<T>` would look like this:

```
BlockingCollection<LogModel> LogQueue = new(32);
Task.Run(async () =>
{
  foreach (var _result in LogQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
  {
    ///Store the log.
  }
});
```

The downside to `BlockingCollection<T>` is that it is blocking. With the sample code above, whenever there isn't an item available, a thread pool thread is blocked.